# Node function execution order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node script with several functions. I'm trying to get it to run as efficiently as possible, so I was wondering how exactly I can control the execution order.

Currently, there are six functions.

Function 1 needs to be finished, then functions 2-5 can execute at the same time, then function 6 needs to be called.

Currently, they are all async functions and I call them like this:

```
func1().then(func2).then(func3).then(func4).then(func5).then(func6).then( ()=> console.log('saved!!!'))
```

How can I improve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` allows you to wait for multiple promises

```
func1().then(result1 => Promise.all([
  func2(),
  func3(),
  func4(),
  func5(),
  func6()
])
.then( ()=> console.log('saved!!!'))
```

I'm assuming the results of each function are irrelevant

If you want access to all the results in the final .then

```
func1().then(result1 => Promise.all([
  result1,
  func2(),
  func3(),
  func4(),
  func5(),
  func6()
])
.then( (results)=> console.log('saved!!!'))
```

Comment: Just worth noting that depending on the implementation of `func2`-`func6` the *may* still run sequentially. Just because a function is async, doesn't necessarily mean it runs in parallel. However, if they *do* work that way, the `Promise.all()` approach at least allows them to not wait for one another.

Comment: @VLAZ of course, without knowing what func1-6 do, the answer is a pineapple :p

Comment: I could go for a nice cold glass of pineapple juice, right now...  :P  That comment was meant for others, just in case. I see a lot of people who assume that `async` magically makes the function execute in a separate thread or similar. So, I wanted to mention that doesn't happen to temper their expectations.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :) I can confirm that they are running on different threads.

Comment: @JonathanZier - no they aren't, not really :p